# Postgres is putting NaN in null values

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, null, nan, psycopg2

I am using `psycopg2` on a python script

The script parses json files, and put them in a Postgres RDS.

When a value is missing on the json file, the script supposed to put skip the specific column

(so it supposed to inert `null` value in the table, but instead it puts `NaN`)

Has anybody encountered this issue?

The part that checks if the column is empty -

```py
if (str(df.loc[0][col]) == "" or df.loc[0][col] is None or str(df.loc[0][col]) == 'None' or str(df.loc[0][col]) == 'NaN' or str(df.loc[0][col]) == 'null'):
    df.drop(col, axis=1, inplace=True)
else:
    cur.execute("call mrr.add_column_to_table('{0}', '{1}');".format(table_name, col))
```

The insertion part -

```py
def copy_df_to_sql(df, conn, table_name):
    if len(df) > 0:
        df_columns = list(df)
        columns = '","'.join(df_columns)  # create (col1,col2,...)
        # create VALUES('%s', '%s",...) one '%s' per column
        values = "VALUES({})".format(",".join(["%s" for _ in df_columns]))
        # create INSERT INTO table (columns) VALUES('%s',...)
        emp = '"'
        insert_stmt = 'INSERT INTO mrr.{} ({}{}{}) {}'.format(table_name, emp, columns, emp, values)
        cur = conn.cursor()
        import psycopg2.extras
        psycopg2.extras.execute_batch(cur, insert_stmt, df.values)
        conn.commit()
        cur.close()
```

Comment: NaN means "Not a Number". Somewhere in your code you are treating the field as a number.

Comment: Can you at least show us the code that is inserting the data?!

Comment: I've added the relevant part from the script

Comment: What type is df?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the reason this is happening is probably because pandas is treating `null` values as `NaN`,

so when I insert a Dataframe into the table in inserts the `null` values as pandas null, which is `NaN`